# is there a default ORDER BY value?

Tags: mysql

I have a dynamic mysql query, and the `ORDER BY` part is hard-coded into the query.

Problem is, I don't know if every query will have an `ORDER BY`, nor do I know which columns will be available to order by.

Is there a default value I can write, so that I can use

`if (empty($order)){$order = "default_value"}`

```
$query = "select ...... ORDER BY $order"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default order to results from queries. If you don't explicitly specify an ORDER BY clause, the data order is undefined. You can only specify `ASC DESC` and some columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unsure about the order why not make it a conditional clause?

```
$order_by = empty($order) ? "" : "ORDER BY " . $order

$query = "select ...... $order_by"
```

Comment: thanks! this was more or less what I was planning, i guess there's no simpler value then..